How can I get the group that has the largest streak of negative numbers in a column and add another condition to filter the groups?
This is an extension to this accepted answer.
My DataFrame:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [-3, -1, -2, -5, 10, -3, -13, -3, -2, 1, 2, -100],
        'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 80, 90, 100, 99, 1, 12]
    }
)

Expected output:
      a    b
5    -3   10
6   -13   80
7    -3   90
8    -2  100

Logic:
a) Selecting the longest streak of negatives in a.
b) If for example there are two streaks that has same size, I want the one that has a greater sum of b. In df there are two streaks with size of 4 but I want the second one because sum of b is greater.
My Attempt:
import numpy as np
s = np.sign(df['a'])
df['g'] = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()
df['size'] = df.groupby('g')['g'].transform('size')
df['b_sum'] = df.groupby('g')['b'].transform('sum')

Edit 1:
I have provided an extra df to clarify the point. I want the negative streaks under any circumstance. In this df the positive streak is longer and its b is greater but I still want the last two rows which is the longest negative streak:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [-0.65, 11, 18, 1, -2, -3],
        'b': [1, 20, 30000, 4322, 300, 3]
    }
)

#output 
4  -2.00    300
5  -3.00      3

This is my attempt to get this output but if there are no negative rows in a dataframe then it throws an error:
df['sign'] = np.sign(df.a)
df['g'] = df.sign.ne(df.sign.shift()).cumsum()
df = df.loc[df.a.lt(0)]
out = df[df.g.eq(df.groupby('g')['b'].agg(['size', 'sum'])
                .query('size == size.max()')['sum'].idxmax())]


You can keep the same logic, just add one extra filtering step (e.g. with query) to get all max sizes, before getting the idxmax of sum of "b":
# negative numbers
m = df['a'].lt(0)
# form groups
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()

out = df[g.eq(df[m]
              .groupby(g)['b'].agg(['size', 'sum'])
              .query('size == size.max()')
              ['sum'].idxmax())]

Output:
    a    b
5  -3   10
6 -13   80
7  -3   90
8  -2  100

Intermediate:
df.groupby(g)['b'].agg(['size', 'sum'])

   size  sum
a           
1     4   10
2     1    5
3     4  280
4     2  100
5     1   12

Or, using your approach (note that this wouldn't guarantee a unique group if two or more have the max length and the same sum of b):
s = np.sign(df['a'])
g = df.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum())

s1 = g['a'].transform('size')
s2 = g['b'].transform('sum')

out = df[s1.eq(s1.max()) & s2.eq(s2.max())]


Can you check Edit 1 in this post please? Your answer does not work with that.

@AmirX true, you need to add a mask to only consider the negative a. See update.

Thanks. If there are no negative values in a then it gives me ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence. Do you have any suggestion?

What would you expect in this case? Either use a try/except or if on the mask with if m.any(): ...

Thanks again. Probably an empty dataframe. I got it.

Code
cond = df['a'] >= 0
grp = cond.cumsum()
idx = (df[~cond].groupby(grp).agg({'a': 'count', 'b': 'sum'})
                .sort_values('b', ascending=False)['a'].idxmax())
out = df[~cond & grp.eq(idx)]

out:
    a    b
5  -3   10
6 -13   80
7  -3   90
8  -2  100


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [-3, -1, -2, -5, 10, -3, -13, -3, -2, 1, 2, -100],
        'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 80, 90, 100, 99, 1, 12]
    }
)

# Determine the groups based on sign changes
m = df['a'] < 0
df['gr'] = gr = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
'''
DataFrame with groups:
      a    b  gr
0    -3    1   1
1    -1    2   1
2    -2    3   1
3    -5    4   1
4    10    5   2
5    -3   10   3
6   -13   80   3
7    -3   90   3
8    -2  100   3
9     1   99   4
10    2    1   4
11 -100   12   5

'''
# Calculate the size of each group where 'a' is negative
gr_size = df.loc[m, 'gr'].value_counts()
'''
Group sizes where 'a' is negative:
gr
1    4
3    4
5    1
'''
# Filter DataFrame for the group with the maximum size
res = df[df['gr'] == gr_size.idxmax()]
'''
Filtered DataFrame for largest group size:
   a  b  gr
0 -3  1   1
1 -1  2   1
2 -2  3   1
3 -5  4   1
'''
# Aggregate statistics for each group
gr_stats = df[m].groupby('gr').agg(size=('gr', 'size'), b_sum=('b', 'sum'))
'''
Group statistics:
    size  b_sum
gr             
1      4     10
3      4    280
5      1     12
'''
# Find the group with the maximum b_sum
max_b_sum_group = gr_stats['b_sum'].idxmax()
'''
Group with maximum b_sum: 3
'''
# Display the rows of the group with maximum b_sum
result = df[df['gr'] == max_b_sum_group]
'''
Rows of the group with maximum b_sum:
    a    b  gr
5  -3   10   3
6 -13   80   3
7  -3   90   3
8  -2  100   3
'''

